# Java 8: hierarchically scan for package-level annotations

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, package, package-info

In Java 8, how can I hierarchically scan for package-level annotations (i.e. annotations in `package-info.java` files)?

e.g., I want to find out for `Class<x.y.z.C>`, the first annotation of type `A` that is found existing on the following packages, in order:

1. `x.y.z`
2. `x.y`
3. `x`
4. (the root package)

When using reflection, I can call `D.class.getPackage()` to get the `Package` for `x.y.z`, and I can see the annotations on that package.

But there is no way to get the `Package` for `x.y` from `x.y.z` (there's no `Package#getParent()` or equivalent method).

I tried using `Package.getPackage("x.y")`, but this returns `null`.

I have not gotten that method to return anything other than `null`.

I've investigated Reflections, Guava, ByteBuddy, Fast Classpath Scanner, etc., but still can't find a way to hierarchically scan for package-level annotations.

Comment: If no classes are defined in package `x.y`, then package `x.y` does not exist… even if there exists a package `x.y.z`.  The existence of a package does not imply the existence of its parent.  (There is no package named `java`, for example.)

Comment: I just realized the answer.  Please see below.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I could find the annotations for a package by doing:

```
Class.forName("x.y.package-info").getAnnotations()
```

Comment: Expect that to fail in future Java versions.  According to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.1), package-info is not a legal identifier for a class.  The fact that it works now is merely an accident.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this in Java 8?

Comment: Yes:  Define a class in that package, even if it's just an empty class.  If the directory doesn't contain at least one class, it's not a package at all.

Comment: I'm writing a generic utility that should be able to be used with anyone's code.  Maybe the best thing to do would be to see if I can find `.class` files in the package using `ClassLoader#getResource()`, then load the first class I find, then get the package from that.  But, since my existing way currently works, and is concise & performant, I'll use that for now.

Comment: in my code `Class.forName(packageName+".package-info").isAnnotationPresent(annotationClass)` throws a `ClassNotFoundException` even if the package-info.java is present in the scanned package